# How do dependency properties work in WPF?

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to understand dependency property and learn how to use it. I'm going through articles and in this article https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/6d590d/wpf-dependency-property/ there's this example:

MainWindow.xaml:

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.DependencyPropertyDemo" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1" Title="DependencyPropertyDemo" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:CarDependencyClass x:Key="carDependencyClass"></local:CarDependencyClass>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Content="Enter Car:" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=MyCar, Source={StaticResource carDependencyClass }}" Name="MyTextCar" Height="25" Width="150" />
        <Button Name="MyButton" Content="Click Me!" Height="25" Click="MyButton_Click" Width="150" Grid.Row="1" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Windows;


namespace WpfApplication1 {
    /// <summary>  
    /// Interaction logic for DependencyPropertyDemo.xaml  
    /// </summary>  
    public partial class DependencyPropertyDemo : Window {
        public DependencyPropertyDemo() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void MyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            CarDependencyClass dpSample = TryFindResource("carDependencyClass") as CarDependencyClass;
            MessageBox.Show(dpSample.MyCar);
        }
    }
    public class CarDependencyClass : DependencyObject {
        //Register Dependency Property  
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CarDependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty", typeof(string), typeof(CarDependencyClass));
        public string MyCar {
            get {
                return (string)GetValue(CarDependencyProperty);
            }
            set {
                SetValue(CarDependencyProperty, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works. I noticed that they registered dependency property with the name "MyProperty" and that it isn't used anywhere in the program. Only normal CLR property MyCar is used in xaml.

But then there's another article https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/simplest-wpf-dependency-property-for-beginners-on-background-color/. And they provide other example:

MainWindow.xaml:

```xml
<Window x:Class="DependencyPropertyTutorial.MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:views="clr-namespace:DependencyPropertyTutorial" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DependencyPropertyTutorial" mc:Ignorable="d" Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BG" Color="Green" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <views:CustomButtonControl SetBackground="{DynamicResource BG}"></views:CustomButtonControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

CustomButtonControl.xaml:

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="DependencyPropertyTutorial.CustomButtonControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DependencyPropertyTutorial"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="btnCustom" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Height="52" Click="btnCustom_Click" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

CustomButtonControl.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;


namespace DependencyPropertyTutorial {
    /// <summary>  
    /// Interaction logic for CustomButtonControl.xaml  
    /// </summary>  
    public partial class CustomButtonControl : UserControl {
        public CustomButtonControl() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty btnDependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SetBackground", typeof(SolidColorBrush), typeof(CustomButtonControl), new PropertyMetadata(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.HotPink), new PropertyChangedCallback(OnSetColorChanged)));
        public SolidColorBrush SetBackground {
            set {
                SetValue(btnDependencyProperty, value);
            }
            get {
                return (SolidColorBrush)GetValue(btnDependencyProperty);
            }
        }
        private void btnCustom_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            this.SetBackground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.IndianRed);
        }
        private static void OnSetColorChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
            CustomButtonControl mycontrol = d as CustomButtonControl;
            mycontrol.callmyInstanceMethod(e);
        }
        private void callmyInstanceMethod(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
            btnCustom.Background = (SolidColorBrush)e.NewValue;
        }
    }
}
```

And here they register dependency property with the name "SetBackground" which is exactly the same as the name of CLR property - SetBackground. And if I change dependency property(the one I registered with Register method) "SetBackground" to something else, like "SetBackgroundDependencyProperty", then I get a XAML exception when trying to run the application. But "SetBackground" dependency property isn't even referenced in xaml anywhere. Only CLR property SetBackground is referenced in XAML at the line

`<views:CustomButtonControl SetBackground="{DynamicResource BG}"></views:CustomButtonControl>`

I also get an error in Visual Studio with this example:
[image]

But when I try to build and run the application, it works.

So my questions are: why in the first example they didn't have to name registered dependency property the same as CLR property, but in the second example, I have to name registered dependency property the same as CLR property. Is there a way to name registered dependency property differently to the CLR property in the second example? Why and how xaml even uses dependency properties, considering xaml references only CLR properties anyway? I checked it and in both projects only CLR properties are referenced from XAML, according to VS IntelliSense. Why do I have to register dependency property with the same name as CLR property -  "SetBackground" when in xaml only CLR property is referenced and it returns SolidColorBrush from the dependency property, anyway:

```
return (SolidColorBrush)GetValue(btnDependencyProperty);
```

Here's the solution with both examples:
https://github.com/KulaGGin/DependencyProperty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First example is a bit dirty, I wouldn't code it such way. There is a good convention to avoid a confusion - to name the DP as the CLR property + 'Property'(**but it's not mandatory!**) and register it as name of CLR property(**if you want to use it as DP in XAML**).
First to your questions:

- First example does work, because of everywhere, where the property `MyCar` being used, it is used as CLR property. If you will try to bind to the `MyCar`, it will fail, because of there is no such a dependency property. To implement the functionality in this example would be enough just to declare a CLR property:
  `public string MyCar { get; set; }`
  instead of all this confusion with dependency property.
- In second example CLR property as well as dependency property `SetBackground` are defined (the name `btnDependencyProperty` for the field is not convenient, but OK). Missunderstanding on your side, is what being used in XAML.
  If you use in XAML **`Binding` or `DynamicResource` the dependency property as well as CLR property are necessary!** Therefore they need to have the same name. If there aren't, then you will get an error.
  If you set the property to the `StaticResource` or directly to the value or even do not use it in XAML, then you will be able to run the application.

Answer (score 1):

DependencyProperty implementation is slightly weird.

The XAML compiler depends on the CLR property wrapper in order to compile, but at runtime bindings ignore it completely and just call GetValue/SetValue on the DP. Therefore the names should match.

Answer (score 0):

There was a typo in the first example. The registered dependency property name needs to be the same as the CLR-backing property.

Declaring a DependencyProperty is a two-stage process:

1. Register the property so that the WPF DependencyProperty system can track it and notify when properties change, etc.
2. Setup a CLR property that gives developers an API to get and set values.

I hope this helps.